# Problem using geom_rect() with facet_grid() with multiple rectangles

Tags: r, ggplot2

## The problem

I am trying to add `geom_rect()` to a `geom_line()` plot with facets. Unfortunately, when I add the rectangles, the facets all display the same way. This exact problem has been discussed in other SO posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68823573/trouble-combining-geom-rect-and-facet-grid-in-ggplot) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512167/using-geom-rect-with-facets). However, in contrast to those posts, I am passing a vector of xmin and xmax values to `geom_rect()`, not just one value.

## Plot example

Here is what I mean:

[image]

And now the same plot, but with an added `geom_rect()` (you can ignore the fact that the rectangles aren't perfectly aligned with the months):

[image]

## Reprex code

Without further ado, here is my reprex. The data comes from the lubridate package.

```
# load packages
library("lubridate")
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")
library("ggplot2")

# summarise time series data
l2 <- lakers %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(as.character(date), format="%Y%m%d")) %>% 
  group_by(week = as.Date(cut.Date(date, breaks = "week")),
           game_type) %>% 
  summarise(points = sum(points, na.rm=T))

# create two vectors for start and end of the month
xmins <- l2 %$% seq(min(week), 
                    max(week), 
                    by="month")
xmaxs <- l2 %$% seq(min(week) %m+% months(1), 
                    max(week)%m+%months(1), 
                    by="month")
```

Here is the code I used for the first plot above (without rectangles):

```
# this plot shows the facets correctly, but is missing the rectangles
ggplot() +
  # geom_rect(
  #   aes(xmin=xmins, xmax=xmaxs, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf),
  #   # xmins/xmaxs have length 6, therefore repeat 3 times
  #   fill= rep(c("lightgrey", "white"), 3),
  #   alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(l2, mapping=aes(x=week, y=points)) +
  facet_grid(game_type ~ .)
```

Here is the code for the second plot above (with rectangles):

```
# this plot shows the rectangles correctly, but messes up the facet
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin=xmins, xmax=xmaxs, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf),
    # xmins/xmaxs have length 6, therefore repeat 3 times
    fill= rep(c("lightgrey", "white"), 3),
    alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(l2, mapping=aes(x=week, y=points)) +
  facet_grid(game_type ~ .)
```

## What I tried so far

I tried moving the data and mapping arguments to the `ggplot()` function instead of the `geom_line()` function, as suggested by other the other posts. But this gives an error:

```
# moving the data and mapping into the ggplot() call causes an error
ggplot(l2, mapping=aes(x=week, y=points)) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin=xmins, xmax=xmaxs, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf),
    # xmins/xmaxs have length 6, therefore repeat 3 times
    fill= rep(c("lightgrey", "white"), 3),
    alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(game_type ~ .)

Error in `geom_rect()`:
  ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
  ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (41)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `xmin` and `xmax`
```

I also tried using `annotate()` instead of `geom_rect()`, but here I run into a similar error:

```
# using annotate instead also doesn't work
ggplot() +
  annotate(
    geom = "rect",
    xmin=xmins, xmax=xmaxs, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf,
    # xmins/xmaxs have length 6, therefore repeat 3 times
    fill= rep(c("lightgrey", "white"), 3),
    alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(l2, mapping=aes(x=week, y=points)) +
  facet_grid(game_type ~ .)

Error in `annotate()`:
  ! Problem while setting up geom aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
  ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (12)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `fill`
```

Notice that there are no problems when `geom_rect()` only contains one rectangle:
[image]

```
ggplot(l2, mapping=aes(x=week, y=points)) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin=xmins[1], xmax=xmaxs[1], ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf),
    # xmins/xmaxs have length 6, therefore repeat 3 times
    fill= "lightgrey",
    alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(game_type ~ .)
```

**I've been stuck on this problems for hours and I appreciate any help you can give me!**

Comment: I don't understand what the desired result is here. Where exactly do you want these rectangles to go? What's wrong with the current output?

Comment: The rectangles (of the second plot) are in the right places. The problem is that the facets suddenly display the same graph (compare the lines in the first and second plot), even though they have different underlying data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `geom_rect()` is a geom, it's tied to whatever is specified for the `data=` argument.  If you don't specify `data=` as an argument for a `geom_rect()` call, the default will use whatever has been specified in either the general `ggplot()` call or in another geom if there is nothing else.

In your code:

```
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(l2, mapping=aes(x=week, y=points)) +
  facet_grid(game_type ~ .)
```

The dataset `l2` is specified as the `data=` for `geom_line()`, and if you add another `geom_rect()` call to that, it will use `l2` as the reference to the data.  You are getting an "aesthetics length" error when passing `xmins` through `aes()` because when mapping aesthetics, `ggplot2` is going to **look in your dataset assigned to `data=` for the column name specified in `aes()`** or expect a vector with a length that corresponds to the same number of observations in your dataset.  `l2` has 41 rows.  You can either specify a name of one of the columns found in `l2` to `aes()` or send a vector with 41 values (kind of like adding your own column "on-the-fly" to the `l2`.  `xmaxs` has only 6 values, so you get that error.

#### Fix for your problem

To fix the problem, just use a separate dataset assigned to `geom_rect()` and then any mapping will apply to the plot *from that specified new dataset*.  Here let's create one:

```
rect_data <- data.frame(
  maxs = xmaxs,
  mins = xmins,
  game_type = c(
    "home", "home", "away", "home", "away", "away"
  )
)
```

The column "game_type" could be left blank, but then you would get the same set of rectangles in every facet.  I picked at random how I wanted the 6 rectangles to be split up among the facets: 2 in home, 1 in away, 1 in home again, and the last 2 in away.  When you specify `rect_data` within `data=` for `geom_rect()`, it works as you intended:

```
p + geom_rect(
  data=rect_data,
  aes(xmin=mins, xmax=maxs),  # within aes.  column names in l2
  ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf,    # note these are outside aes
  alpha=0.2, fill="blue")
```

[image]

I don't know how OP wants to separate/split your rectangles of `xmins` and `xmaxs`, but you will need to specify how to do that with another column called `game_type`, since that is the column name expected and used to map the particular facets.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot for your answer, I fully understand it now! It seems like for drawing rectangles with geom_rect(), using a separate data.frame is always the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your rect layer is sharing the same data as the line layer. It would be better to store the rectangle data in it's own data.frame. For example

```
rectdf <- data.frame(xmins, xmaxs, fillc=rep(c("lightgrey", "white"), 3))

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin=xmins, xmax=xmaxs, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill=fillc),
    alpha=0.5, data=rectdf) +
  geom_line(l2, mapping=aes(x=week, y=points)) +
  facet_grid(game_type ~ .) + 
  scale_fill_identity()
```

this will result in
[image]

Comment: This code works perfectly! I noticed, however, that the colors will be weird if I leave out `scale_fill_identity()`. Specifically, I get red and blue instead of grey and white, plus there will be a legend on the right. Could you maybe explain why `scale_fill_identity()` is necessary here to make the fill colors work as they should? I read the documentation but don't fully understand it yet.

Comment: It's because I moved the `fill=` from outside the `aes()` to inside. Values on the inside are translated into graphical elements via different scales. Normally you don't actually put color values in the fill column, so you need to tell ggplot specifically to use those exact values for colors by specifying `scale_fill_identity` rather than having ggplot map unique values to colors.